# How to group the documents which I just unwinded in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, grouping

This is the initial document. I applied $unwind on "colors" and another $unwind on "colors.sizes". But now am not able to group them back. How is that done?

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ef838255c959771c46fc917"),
  "created": ISODate("2017-03-04T18:30:00.000Z"),
  "updated": ISODate("2020-06-28T00:49:23.000Z"),
  "status": "active",
  "productId": "3828",
  "tags": {
    "colors": ["BEIGE", "BLACK", "BLUE", "GREEN", "GREY", "LIGHT BEIGE", "LIGHT PINK", "NAVY", "PINK", "WHITE"],
    "size": ["39", "39.5", "40", "40.5", "41", "41.5", "42", "42.5", "43", "43.5", "44", "44.5", "45", "45.5", "46"],
    "category": ["SHOES", "SNEAKERS", "MENS SHOES & ACCESSORIES"],
    "price": ["3400.00", "1360.00", "2040.00", "1700.00", "45575.00"],
    "season": ["SS(2020)", "AW(2019)", "SS(2019)", "AW(2018)", "SS(2017)", "AW(2016)", "SS(2016)", "SS(2015)"],
    "hash": ["ACTIVE", "ANKLE", "BLUSH", "COLLAR", "COLOUR", "DESIGNER", "FOIL", "GOLD-TONE", "LACE-UP", "LEATHER", "LOW", "LOW TOP", "ORIGINAL", "PADDED", "ROUND", "ROUND TOE", "RUBBER", "SIGNATURE", "TONAL"]
  },
  "name": "ORIGINAL ARCHILLES LOW SNEAKER",
  "description": "",
  "brand": "COMMON PROJECTS",
  "styleCode": "220036200",
  "availableOnline": true,
  "colors": [{
    "images": [],
    "_id": ObjectId("5ef838255c959771c46fc918"),
    "colorId": "1",
    "color": "WHITE",
    "hexCode": "#FFFFFF",
    "status": "active",
    "sizes": [{
      "extraInfo": [{
        "title": "Size And Fit",
        "text": "Product measures: Heel 3cm (1.2\"). True to size"
      }, {
        "title": "Information",
        "text": "Designer colour: White. Leather. Rubber outsole. Made in Italy"
      }],
      "_id": ObjectId("5ef838255c959771c46fc919"),
      "sizeId": "1",
      "neo": "0220003258813",
      "size": "39",
      "originalPrice": "3400.00",
      "sellingPrice": "3400.00",
      "discountPercent": "0.00",
      "status": "active"
    }, {
      "extraInfo": [{
        "title": "Size And Fit",
        "text": "Product measures: Heel 3cm (1.2\"). True to size"
      }, {
        "title": "Information",
        "text": "Designer colour: White. Leather. Rubber outsole. Made in Italy"
      }],
      "_id": ObjectId("5ef838255c959771c46fc91a"),
      "sizeId": "2",
      "neo": "0220111220849",
      "size": "39.5",
      "originalPrice": "3400.00",
      "sellingPrice": "3400.00",
      "discountPercent": "0.00",
      "status": "active"
    }, {
      "extraInfo": [{
        "title": "Size And Fit",
        "text": "Product measures: Heel 3cm (1.2\"). True to size"
      }, {
        "title": "Information",
        "text": "Designer colour: White. Leather. Rubber outsole. Made in Italy"
      }],
      "_id": ObjectId("5ef838255c959771c46fc91b"),
      "sizeId": "3",
      "neo": "0220004218564",
      "size": "40",
      "originalPrice": "3400.00",
      "sellingPrice": "3400.00",
      "discountPercent": "0.00",
      "status": "active"
    }]
  }, ]
}
```

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
  {$match:{"productId":"3828"}},
  {$unwind:"$colors"},
  {$unwind:"$colors.sizes"},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from:"inventories",
      localField: "colors.sizes.neo",
      foreignField: "sku",
      as:"colors.sizes.stores"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: what do you mean by groping them back? do you want unwinded result to go back to the initial state?

Comment: @AnuragWagh I unwinded 2 times. I performed some operations. Now I want to group them back with the output.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite operator of `$unwind` is `$group`

#### Explanation

1. We `$group` by `productId` + `colors[*]._id` fields grouping `root`, `colors` and `sizes` separately. 
   **Note:** You can define each variable separately like this:

---

```
created: {$first:"$created"},
updated: {$first:"$updated"},
...
OR
use aggregation variable $$ROOT which contains entire document fields
```

---

2. We "merge" each variables into single object and move into root level. 
   **Note:** If we don't use `$replaceRoot`, the data structure will looks like this:

---

```
{
   _id: "...",
   root: {
     _id: "...",
     ...
     colors:{
       ...
       sizes:[...]
     }
   }
}
```

---

**Note:** Unfortunately, MongoDB doesn't allow merge subkeys like this:

---

```
{
  $mergeObjects:[
    "$root",
    {"colors":"$colors"},
    {"colors.sizes":"$sizes"} <-- Not allowed
  ]
}
```

So we have to use `$objectToArray` + `$map` + `$arrayToObject` operators

```
$objectToArray - transforms object into array
{"hello": "world"} ---> [{"k":"hello", "v":"world"}]

$map - iterates array and transforms array content. 
       In this case, we replace `sizes` field with `sizes` from the 1st step

$objectToArray - transforms "special" array into object
[{"k":"hello", "v":"world"}] ---> {"hello": "world"}
```

3. Now we group only by `productId` and group `colors` and `root` values separately
4. We finish merging variables and transform into desired object (same as 2nd step)

---

Add these steps into your pipeline:

```
{
   $group: {
      "_id": {
        productId: "$productId",
        colors: "$colors._id"
      },
      "root": {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      },
      "colors": {
        $first: "$colors"
      },
      "sizes": {
        $push: "$colors.sizes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$root",
          {
            "colors": {
              $arrayToObject: {
                $map: {
                  input: { $objectToArray: "$colors" },
                  as: "color",
                  in: {
                    k: "$$color.k",
                    v: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $eq: [ "$$color.k", "sizes" ] },
                        "$sizes",
                        "$$color.v"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "root": {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      },
      "colors": {
        $push: "$colors"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$root",
          { "colors": "$colors" }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HyfmfvsUcgK)